# Activating screen saver from AppleScript in Mountain Lion

Tags: applescript, macos, screensaver

I had a script that I used to use to activate my screen saver, and it no longer works in Mountain Lion.

It was a shell script that called an AppleScript script:

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript /Users/lorin/scripts/lockscreen.scpt
```

This is what the `lockscreen.scpt` file looks like:

```
tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" 
        activate 
end tell
```

If I bring up `lockscreen.scpt` in the AppleScript Editor, I get the "Choose Application" dialog popping up asking "Where is ScreenSaverEngine?"

Anybody know the Mountain Lion-y way to activate the screen saver?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That is a nice way of starting a random screen saver.
If, however, you'd simply like to start the active screen saver, you can use this in Mountain Lion:

```
tell application "System Events" 
    start current screen saver
end tell
```

Answer (score 7):

This works in ML:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ss to screen saver "Random"
    start ss
end tell
```

"Random" can be replaced with your choice, "Flurry" or "Shell" and so on.

Source Disclosure: http://hintsforums.macworld.com/showthread.php?t=111478

Comment: How do I make it stop the screen saver?  I tried `tell application "System Events" to stop screen saver`

Comment: @Jayen `tell application "System Events" to quit current screen saver`

Answer (score 3):

`tell application "ScreenSaverEngine" to run`

Comment: I had issues with `tell application "System Events" to start current screen saver`. if i ran that script multiple times using a keybinding i would have multiple screensavers stacked, only the first would close.  This answer however, worked perfectly for me.