# Activating Mountain Lion screen saver from Applescript, part 2

Tags: macos, applescript, screensaver

[This example](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/57914/activating-screen-saver-from-applescript-in-mountain-lion) was shown earlier:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ss to screen saver "Random"
    start ss
end tell
```

Is there an incantation instead of "Random" to display a slideshow from the selected folder in the screen saver preferences?

Comment: Can you please add a link to the earlier question?

Comment: Linked it in above in "This example"

Answer (score 1):

### On Mountain Lion (10.8)

This AppleScript will start the screen saver with the selected folder.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set ss to screen saver "iLifeSlideshows"
    start ss
end tell
```

### Lion (10.7) and earlier

First select the appropriate sources/folders by clicking the **Shuffle** item in the screen savers list, then checking one or more items in the dialog that appears.

Then start the screen saver as as in the Mountain Lion section, but change `iLifeSlideshows` to `screensaver.shuffle`.

[image: screen saver prefs]

Comment: **Shuffle** isn't valid/available in Mountain Lion

Comment: Oh, my bad, on Lion at the moment, that escaped my notice. I don't have a 10.8 machine handy at the moment, but you can get the names of the available screensavers with `tell application "System Events" to get name of screen savers`, which may reveal something useful.

Comment: Thanks!! The answer is iLifeSlideshows.  Oddly, screensaver.shuffle is listed as valid in the "get name of screen savers" output, but when that is used on Mountain Lion I get a flickering, floating text box stating "You cannot use the Shuffle screen saver with this version of Mac OS X.  Please contact the vendor to get a newer version of the screen saver."  Again, thanks for your help!!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you found something that worked. I integrated that into my answer, let me know if I missed anything.